# Refresh image cache in Facebook app?

Tags: jquery, facebook, xhtml

can anybody recommend any tips for clearing cached images in a facebook iframe html app?  Every time we alter content in the page the altered images take ages to refresh in Firefox?

Is there anyway to force the cache to clear or to make the image caching expire?

Cheers
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append a query string or timestamp to your URL to force Facebook to reload the image:

```
http://xy.tld/images/myimage.png?v=1
```